# Change default Text Material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using Material-table ( https://material-table.com/#/ ) in a project, I am trying to change the default texts such as search, rows .. Here's a picture of what my table looks like. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) you have a property called `localization` which receives an object with all localization settings.

e.g.

If you want to change the search bar placeholde, you need to pass `localization.toolbar.searchPlaceholder` to change the search placeholder.

```
<MaterialTable
  localization={{
      toolbar: {
          searchPlaceholder: 'your string'
      }
  }}
  ...
/>
```